# Block jquery mobile scripts and meta viewpoint for desktop users

Tags: javascript, mobile, media-queries

Brand to Stack Overflow and to mobile design.

I am using JQUERY Mobile.  And I feel I have a basic understanding of Media Queries.  But the one problem I cannot find the answer for (So I may may looking at this incorrectly) is how do you NOT run the following on the page when a desktop user is browsing?

As this is not defined by CSS, media queries wouldn't work.  If javascript works, could someone give me a hand with the coding.  I tried the following but I do not know javascript:

```
<script>
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 641) 
{    
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
}
</script >
```

I know I can use a mobile PHP sniffer, but prefer not to go that route due to "upkeep".

Thank you in advance

EDIT:

Looks likes the following will work (Example #4).

http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php

But my concern is why does it seem like more people aren't having this issue?  Am I missing something very obvious?  If you are using the then same page for both mobile and desktop and you are using jquery mobile scripts, you don't want them running for the desktop users.

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the mobile device to do. Two ways you can target are:

1. **Checking User Agent Serverside**

   ```
   if( strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'Android') ||
       strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'webOS') ||
       strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPhone') ||
       strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPod')
       ){
       // Send Mobile Site
   }
   ```
2. **Checking User Agent Clientside**

   ```
   if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) ||
       navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) ||
       navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) ||
       navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) ||
       ){
    // Send Mobile Site
   }
   ```

And if they seem to use a mobile device, make sure you display the Mobile CSS and Viewport Meta. I don't think `viewport` meta would affect the desktop users.

Comment: Thank you Praveen.  But doesn't that put me in the same position as using a sniffer?  I will need to update the code whenever a new OS is introduced (which seems monthly as of late!).

Comment: Monthly? What do you mean? You don't need to update anything in this case.

Comment: For example, Windows has a new OS for mobile.  Wouldn't that need to be added?

Comment: Yeah, kinda... But once you will add, that will be permanent, no need for every version.